# Flutter: Limit frame rate to reduce battery drain

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a Flutter app that has lots of animations and stays in the foreground for a long time.

The app runs very smooth and I measured the FPS to hit 120 on iPhone 13 Pro.

Is there a way to limit the FPS in Flutter to a value, e.g. 30? I know that 30 will be a bit less smooth than 120, but for my use-case that’s totally fine!

My current idea is to override scheduleFrame of the WidgetBindings and delay the call to limit the FPS, or is there some other way?